# Remove lines getting empty after BeautifulSoup decompose

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to strip certain HTML tags and their content from a file with `BeautifulSoup`. How can I remove lines that get empty after applying `decompose()`? In this example, I want the line between `a` and `3` to be gone, as this is where the `<span>...</span>` block was, but not the line in the end.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup     

Rmd_data = 'a\n<span class="answer">\n2\n</span>\n3\n'
print(Rmd_data)

#OUTPUT
# a
# <span class="answer">
# 2
# </span>
# 3
# 
# END OUTPUT

soup = BeautifulSoup(Rmd_data, "html.parser")
answers = soup.find_all("span", "answer")
for a in answers:
    a.decompose()

Rmd_data = str(soup)
print(Rmd_data)

# OUTPUT
# a
#
# 3
# 
# END OUTPUT
```

Comment: Can you post what you want your output to look like?

Comment: @serk, I did, and elaborated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that BeatifulSoup does not offer a prettify() option. Instead of manipulating the html manually you could re-parse your html:

```
str(BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser'))
```

As always, enjoy.

Comment: this ^^

been looking all over, should be the chosen answer!
doesn't affect tags, no need to handle via .text

`soup = str(BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser'))`

after all other operations

Answer (score 0):

For removing empty lines most easy will be via re

```
import re
re.sub(r'[\n\s]+', r'\n', text, re.MULTLINE)
```

Comment: But this removes all the multi-lines, I want only those affected by `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: text is key variable. You can size it to what is needed

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. How would your line apply to my example?

Comment: I think it's like this : `Rmd_data = re.sub(r'[\n\s]+', r'\n', str(soup), re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @EttoreRizza This also leaves damage in parts of my file that is not contained within the original spans